# Hadoop Hive Update, Insert and delete for text file format?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've table in Hive I want to perform DML Operation in that table.That table is stored as text file and delimited with (,). Does it is possible do DML operation in this table? If so what configuration I need do? Does I need do any changes in my table structure (like bucketing)?

I am using hive latest version (cloudera 5.4.2)

Thanks
Venkadesan

Answer (score 0):

The DML Operations syntax is similar to SQL.

No changes required in your table structure as well.

> INSERT INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1[=val1],
>   partcol2[=val2] ...)] VALUES values_row [, values_row ...]
>
> DELETE FROM tablename [WHERE expression]
>
> UPDATE tablename SET column = value [, column = value ...] [WHERE
>   expression]

for more check the documentation
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML